# execute command to new loaded content from ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got some problem with jquery.

```
<select class='my-select' id='exist_select'></select> 

<div id='target'></div>

<script>
$.ajax({
    type        : 'GET',
    url         : "<?php echo site_url().'rekap/get_akun?id_subkom=' ?>"+id_subkom,
    dataType    : 'json', 
    success: function(data){
        var select = '';
        for (var key in data){
            select = '<select class="my-select" id="select'+data[key]+'"></select>';
        }
        $('div#target').html(select);

        $('.my-select').append($('<option>', {
            value: 100,
            text: 'Added option',
        }))
    })
})
</script>
```

The selects was successfully loaded. As you see, I tried to make HTML selects. Then append spesific option manually for each select. 
Unlucky, It doesn't work. But it works on `#exist_select`.

I have no idea. Please help me.

Comment: Please don't echo your site_url() directly from php into javascript.

Consider using an appropriate escaping/encoding.

echo json_encode(site_url());

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your code in a document ready statement, second your loop only gets the first element, you need to use concatenation to append the rest,3th you can append the option directly in the select:

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    type        : 'GET',
    url         : "<?php echo site_url().'rekap/get_akun?id_subkom=' ?>"+id_subkom,
    dataType    : 'json', 
    success: function(data){
        var select = '';
        for (var key in data){
            select += '<select class="my-select" id="select'+data[key]+'"><option  value="100">Added option</option></select>';
        }
        $('div#target').html(select);
    })
})

})
```

Comment: Thx. I just realize that my main problem is in the event listener. If I put a button and make an event listener on click, the append command works. Can you give me some advise with this?

Answer (score 0):

Event listeners can only be attached to elements that are in the DOM, not elements that don't exist at the time.

For dynamically created elements, you need to use the [.on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('body').on('change', '.my-select', function(){
    alert('here');
});
```

Comment: its called event delegation

Comment: Yes but as per the question his issue related to change event, He is not able to find the event for other select except #exist_select

Comment: can you put $('div#target') html?